# See check ins on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, checkin

I want customers to check in to my page/place and give them discounts for checking in a few times.

Is it possible to get a list of everyone who has checked in to my local business page?

In the Facebook API I've found something about check ins. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/checkin But I don't know it still works or how it works.

**EDIT**

unfortunately it's not available in the newest Facebook API anymore

Comment: According to [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/checkin) it appears that this feature was discontinued in the newer versions of the API.

Comment: I do now that, but I want to know if there is another way to get see checkins

Comment: _“and give them discounts for checking in a few times”_ – that would violate Platform Policies (please go read them) – you are not allowed to reward users for such actions.

Comment: @CBroe On this site: [link](http://www.jonloomer.com/2013/01/28/facebook-graph-search-rank-check-in-deals/) they talk about 4 deals. One of them is Loyalty: Offer a discount or freebie for checking in a certain number of times. So would that be against their own policies?

Comment: Perhaps the FaceBook DEALS program is what oyu are looking for.
http://samsonmedia.net/blog/2011/06/how-to-create-a-facebook-check-in-deal/

Comment: I guess you are keeping the login data in a database, so you can add an extra column with a counter and increment it every time a customer do the login.